# Using composer to autoload library outside of vendor/ folder

Tags: php, composer-php

Vagrant and mounted folders do not play nice with composer using relative paths to folders added in via the

"autoload" option.

It in-correctly detects what the baseDir is and therefore will fail to register the namespaces.

Has anyone come across this before?

For isntance

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Inventory\\" : "./core/src/inventory/" }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `composer install` from the VM instead from your host? Or, perhaps a simple `composer dump-autoload` will regenerate the paths.

Answer (score 0):

The autoloading is supposed to be given relative to the path where the `composer.json` file is located. I've never seen that path starting with a dot, so first of all I'd try to get rid of that and see how that works.

Second thing that might simply be is that you got the autoloading wrong in some detail and mistake it for being something related to Vagrant. The way you currently set it up, a class named `\Inventory\Foo` must be located in the path `core/src/inventory/Foo.php`. Can you verify that this is the case? Otherwise please give an example of an existing class name and it's file name.

Comment: Sven i think it's more to do with the symlinks. I don't think composer is capable of evaluating symlinks correctly and thus is creating incorrect paths for things when it is run.